# Django - Annotate within for loop - what is the difference between my two codes

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to sum up two columns in a view with `values()` and `annotate()`.

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 0 |
| 5 | -2 |

Currently calling "total" will return the total for each row and not the overall total.

Returning in template

```
5
3
```

instead of

```
8
```

I believe this is because I print the total in a for loop. What confuses me is that I have an almost similar code working perfectly fine in another view.

How can I get the total of the several rows together?

**Update** to answer Willem's question - timestamp is used to order the list of model objects when they are created.

This was not the result I initially wanted when I wrote the code. But realised I could use this view to render a report of the objects as they are being created, so I added the timestamp to order the objects starting with the most recent one.

This is not relevant for my problem. I removed it to avoid confusion. Sorry for this.

**views**

```
def function(request, userprofile_id):
venue = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user).values('venue')
points_cummulated_per_user_per_venue = Itemised_Loyalty_Card.objects.filter(user=userprofile_id).filter(venue=request.user.userprofile.venue).values('venue__name','timestamp').annotate(sum_points=Sum('add_points')).annotate(less_points=Sum('use_points')).annotate(total=F('add_points')-F('use_points')).
return render(request,"main/account/venue_loyalty_card.html",{'venue':venue,'points_cummulated_per_user_per_venue':points_cummulated_per_user_per_venue})
```

**template**

```
{%for model in points_cummulated_per_user_per_venue %}
Total: {{model.total}}
{%endfor%}
```

**models**

```
class Itemised_Loyalty_Card(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    add_points = models.IntegerField(name = 'add_points', null = True, blank=True, default=0)
    use_points = models.IntegerField(name= 'use_points', null = True, blank=True, default=0)

class Venue(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name",max_length=100, blank=True)
```

Comment: WHat are column1 and column 2 here? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Furthermore please share the relevant models.

Comment: All updated. What I am trying to achieve is to sum up the 2 model fields (add points and use_points) together to get the total points.

Comment: Pleae include the model of the `Venue`, what is `timestamp` doing here? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: I added the model and a bit more explanation. I should have removed the `timestamp` from the code, as it made my request more confusion. I only added it as I realised the code as I wrote it was not rendering what I was looking for but could be used to render a report of the objects created. Did I answer your question? (thanks for sticking around!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please *don't* use `.values(…)`. I wrote a [short article that describes several problems with this <sup>[Django-antipatterns]</sup>](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html).

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum


def function(request, userprofile_id):
    profile = request.user.profile
    venue = profile.venue
    venues = Venue.objects.filter(itemised_loyalty_card__user=profile).annotate(
        total=Sum(
            F('itemised_loyalty_card__add_points')
            - F('itemised_loyalty_card__use_points')
        )
    )

    return render(
        request,
        'main/account/venue_loyalty_card.html',
        {
            'venue': venue,
            'venues': venues,
        },
    )
```

then in your template you enumerate over the `venues` and render the total:

```
{%for item in venues %}
    {{ item.name }}: {{ item.total }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`Itemised_Loyalty_Card`</s> to `ItemisedLoyaltyCard`.

Comment: That's well impressive you managed to completely change my code so quickly without much background and still get the expected result. (only had to re-add a filter for venue). I am still trying to map the logic. I wish I could up vote you twice! If you dont mind me asking what sort of risk do I take by writing my model `Model_1` instead of `Model1`? I have loads of models written in this pattern and wondering if I need to change everything.